# Javascript function unable to access CSS styling

Tags: javascript

Javascript function unable to access CSS styling

I can't figure out why the Javascript function below is unable to access any of the CSS styling! The demo script's
idea is for a small menu of options to appear at mouse coordinates when you Right-click. Code follows...

```
      <style type="text/css">

      .MiniMenuText {
      Font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
      Font-size: 11px;
      Font-weight: Normal;
      Font-style: Normal;
      Text-decoration: None;
      Text-align: Left;
      Color: #FFFFFF;
      Height:0;}

      .MiniMenuBox {
      -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
      Padding: 1px;
      Width: 175px;
      Height: 80px;
      Background-color: #686868;
      Border-style: Solid;
      Border-color: #A0AAA0;
      Border-width: 1px;
      Text-align: Center;}

      <!--
      A:hover {Color:Black; Background-color:#FFFFFF;}
      -->

      </style>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function RunMiniMenu() {

      var X=window.event.clientX;
      var Y=window.event.clientY;

      document.write('<div Class="MiniMenuBox"; Style="Position:Absolute; Left:'+X+'px;              Top:'+Y+'px;";>');
      document.write('<a Href=""; Target="_blank"; Class="MiniMenuText";>Option 1</a><br>');
      document.write('<a Href=""; Target="_blank"; Class="MiniMenuText";>Option 2</a><br>');
      document.write('<a Href=""; Target="_blank"; Class="MiniMenuText";>Option 3</a><br>');
      document.write('<a Href=""; Target="_blank"; Class="MiniMenuText";>Option 4</a><br>');
      document.write('<a Href=""; Target="_blank"; Class="MiniMenuText";>Option 5</a></div>');
      }

      </script>

      <body oncontextmenu="RunMiniMenu(); return false;"; </body>
```

Comment: Your `<body>` tag is missing a closing `>`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors but styling is completely missing!

Comment: You can't use `document.write` in event handler, or anywhere after the document is loaded.

Comment: @duri I vote for deprecating `document.write` in its entirety ;-)

Comment: Jan's right. Forget about `document.write`. It's a bane. Better use one of the many JavaScript templating libraries (which I happen to wrote one, hehe => http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/).

Comment: Wats up with the Uppercase Lowercase mix!

Comment: Err, so is the general consensus for a complete rewrite… different approach? :)

Answer (score 2):

One error is the `;` you put after every HTML attribute. The other one is mentioned by Michael Berkowski (the missing `>` within the `body` tag).

One more thing to keep in mind: When you write to the `document` AFTER the page has fully loaded (i.e. after the document is closed), a write to it will yield a new document that lacks the styles.

**EDIT**

```
<style>
    /* Your styles here */
</style>

...
<body oncontextmenu="runMiniMenu();">
    <!-- Whatever markup you need comes here! -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function runMiniMenu(e) {
            var X = e.clientX,
                Y = e.clientY;

            var div = document.createElement('div');

            div.createAttribute('class', 'MiniMenuBox');
            div.createAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; left:'+X+'px ...

            for ( var i=1; i < 6; i++ ) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.createAttribute('target', '_blank');

                // You get the point!
                ...

                div.appendChild(a);
            }

            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);

            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've just tested that if I close the body tag with a > it doesn't work! :)

Comment: Btw, I also tested that removing the ; after attributes makes no difference.

Comment: I know, these are syntax errors that browsers silently drop (nevertheless, you shouldn't do them in the first place). The real problem is that you are opening the document again, writing to it after it has been closed

Comment: Thanks for your code also, I’ll test it later because now I gotta rush to my wife’s b-day party! :)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is correct about the errors in your syntax and about document.write. Abandon document.write and you will be much better off.

If you are simply trying to put that html in the body tag after the page loads then I would use `innerHTML`

So it would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function RunMiniMenu() {

  var X=window.event.clientX;
  var Y=window.event.clientY;
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");

  body.innerHTML = "<div class='MiniMenuBox' style='position:absolute; left:"+X+"px;
          top:"+Y+"px;'><a href=''; target='_blank'; class='MiniMenuText'>Option 1</a><br/></div>";
  }

  </script>

  <body onload="RunMiniMenu(); return false;"> </body>
```

Comment: Please note that the little menu is intended to be called when certain buttons are Right-clicked. Everywhere else on the screen the browser’s default right-click menu function is ok. That’s why I wasn’t after an event handler etc.

Comment: Thanks, but your method is returning two errors:


1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Highlighting the line "body.innerHTML..."


and 2. Uncaught ReferenceError: RunMiniMenu is not defined

Highlighting the line "<body onload=...."